# How to detect in PHP, if it is running on Apache, Nginx or some other webserver?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, web-server, nginx

First I know this variable : `_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]`

In one of my application, I want to check from PHP script which webserver it is running on.
Basically it will be a wordpress plugin which will help Bloggers tweak some configure.

I have created separate process for Apache & Nginx and was also thinking about releasing code as 2 different wordpress plugins.

Then I just got curious to know if there is a FULLPROOF way in PHP to detect webservers flawlessly.

Please consider all cases :: Apache, Nginx, Apache + Nginx, PHP as Apache module, PHP using fastcgi, php-fpm, lighttpd, IIS, etc.

Also its critical for my application to detect combos and proxies presence.

Thanks,

-Rahul

Answer (score 10):

Short answer is that its impossible to deterministically identify what webserver is in use. The closest you'll get is the value of $_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"].

It is possible to get a fairly good idea what software is running at a [particular URL by application fingerprinting but that's very *very* complicated - and it'll only tell you what's terminating the HTTP connection - it may be a proxy.

What you see in phpinfo() will not show the web server for [fast]cgi and it'll only show what the adminstrator chooses to make available on other systems.

> Also its critical for my application to detect combos and proxies presence.

I have no idea what you mean by 'combos'. As for proxies....there is no way to tell that either.

Perhaps if you explained **why** you need this information and what value it has to you then we might be able to make a more informed guess as to an answer which might suit your needs.

C.

Comment: By cambo I simply mean - some users choose Nginx as front-end web server and then use Apache to run PHP. One case is that they want to run cpanel and nginx together.
Now in my application, in one section, I want to guide users for some complex rewrite rule based on webserver. In above apache+nginx case, which web-server my PHP script will detect?
I

Answer (score 0):

Someone on the PHP Manual site posted a [way to get](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) `phpinfo()` variables into an array, there's lots of information there but also the `System` where php is running, maybe you can use that. Look at the comments.

Also, detecting proxies is not that easy, you can use http headers (like `Via`) but there're a lot of ways that it can go wrong.

Comment: thanks for your answer and help. I know via headers cannot be trusted and that is the reason I am seeking some help.